# Visual Studio 2008 LINQ delete rows not working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-entities

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with .NET Framework 3.5.

I am trying to do what I had thought would be a simple deletion of some rows using LINQ to entities.

I have a simple SQL Server database back end and I am using Data Entity Framework to access it.  I have done nothing to the default behavior created in the EDMX.

I am attempting the following code:

```
            myDB.Dispose();
            myDB = new EChODatabaseConnection();


            //get our equipment list of requested equipment
            var OldEquip = from u in myDB.dbEquipmentRequestedSet
                                          where u.iRequestID == requestID
                                          select u;
            myDB.DeleteObject(OldEquip);

            myDB.SaveChanges();
```

It gets to the db.DeleteObject(OldEquip) and generates the following error:

*"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."*

I have verified that there is something in OldEquip before the line of code is executed.

I added the first two lines of code(Dispose and new) on the off chance there was an issue with previous code.

**EDIT**
The dbEquipmentRequestedSet looks like this:

```
iRequestID  (in db an int)
sCode       (in db a varchar(50))
SCodePrefix (in db a varchar(10))
```

I use a composite primary key based upon iRequestID and sCode.

**EDIT2**
To clarify, in almost all cases, the OldEquip query will result in more than one result.

From the answers so far, it appears that I will have to manually go through each entry to delete.

Is there a more elegant solution?  Maybe by using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to delete multiples. Try this:

```
var OldEquip = (from u in myDB.dbEquipmentRequestedSet
                            where u.iRequestID == requestID
                            select u)
                    .ToList();

foreach(var item in OldEquip)
{
    myDB.DeleteObject(item);
}
```

The likely cause if that `DeleteObject` accepts an object, which should be an entity that is contained in the ObjectStateManager.Your code currently passed it an `ObjectQuery<T>` which isn't contained in the ObjectStateManager.

More at this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/032295ec-01c5-469c-9231-f465174e2885/).

Comment: The query will generate more than one value. *adding* edit to show dbEquipmentRequestSet.

Comment: Yes, the query is 99% likely to result in a multiple.

Comment: @Campbell:  So there is no method to delete them all at once?  I had tried to do a stored procedure for the delete and got nowhere fast :/

Answer (score 0):

`OldEquip` in this case is of type IQueryable. You can only delete actual entities, so you will have to modify the LINQ statement to something like:

```
var OldEquip = (from u in myDB.dbEquipmentRequestedSet
                where u.iRequestID == requestID
                select u).First();
```

or if the query returns multiple values, loop through all the results in the IQueryable using `foreach` and delete all items separately.

Comment: I just tried this with ToList and it gives me the same error message :(

Comment: @John Stone, `ToList != First`.  If you want to delete multiple you will have to enumerate them and call DeleteObject multiple times.

Comment: You have to do a `foreach` and delete each item in the list separately. My original wording was somewhat unclear about this, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have some extension methods I use to delete multiple objects at once if you want to use them:

```
    public static void DeleteAll(this ObjectContext context, IEnumerable<object> collection)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection.ToList())
        {
            context.DeleteObject(item);
        }
    }

    public static void DeleteAll<TEntity>(this ObjectSet<TEntity> context, IEnumerable<TEntity> collection) where TEntity : class
    {
        foreach (var item in collection.ToList())
        {
            context.DeleteObject(item);
        }
    }
```